# Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property from inner enum class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

Having this domain class and using hibernate 3.2.6 integrated with JPA under spring 3.2.4

```
@Entity
public class PriorityDeviceKeyword {

    public enum PriorityDeviceKey {

        ALL     ("ALL",    "ALL DEVICES"),
        IOS     ("IOS",    "IOS"),
        ANDROID ("ANDROID","ANDROID");

        private final String name;

        private final String id;

        private PriorityDeviceKey(String name, String id) {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "key")
    private PriorityDeviceKey key;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "t_priority_device_set", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "priority_device__id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<PriorityDevice> priorityDevices;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public PriorityDeviceKey getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(PriorityDeviceKey key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public List<PriorityDevice> getPriorityDevices() {
        return priorityDevices;
    }

    public void setPriorityDevices(List<PriorityDevice> priorityDevices) {
        this.priorityDevices = priorityDevices;
    }
}
```

When executing this query that I have below method in my DAO class that I execute

```
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Set<PriorityDevices> findPriorityAreas(PriorityDevicesKey key) {

        String jpql = "from PriorityDevices as pak where pak.key.name = :keyName";

        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
        query.setParameter("keyName", key.getName());       
        List<PriorityDevices> priorityDevices =  query.getResultList();
        return new HashSet<PriorityDevices>(priorityDevices);
    }
```

I get this Exception thrown by the application:

```
2015-01-14 13:14:50,936 ERROR [com.controller.errors.Error500Controller] - Application thrown an exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: name of: com.domain.PriorityDevicesKeyword [from com.domain.PriorityDevicesKeyword as
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:624)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:96)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor440.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think these changes may work for you:

```
@Column(name = "key")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private PriorityAreaKey key;
```

and

```
String jpql = "from PriorityAreaKeyword as pak where pak.key = :keyName";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
query.setParameter("keyName", key);
```

Comment: You don't need to add `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`. It only tells the db on how the enum should be stored. That said: default storage is by ordinal so care should be taken to only add new enums after the existing ones. When stored as string only changes in name are problematic while changes in order are not.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate stores enums as an oridnal. Or, when the field is annotated with `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`, as a string with the short name of the Enum. When annotated valid names would be `{ALL, IOS, ANDROID}`. Either way there is only a single field, the properties of the enum itself are not stored, they are constant after all.

If you want to query for an enum value you have to to query for `pak.key = :key` and use `key` as the parameter. Hibernate will do the required translation to ordinal or string.